# What's the correct way to test if a variable is a number in PHP?

Tags: php, integer

When I fetch data from a database, the result is a string even if it has an number value. Here's what I mean:

```
// An integer
$int=10;
if(is_int($int)) // Returns true
...

// A string
$int='10';
if(is_int($int)) // Returns false
...
```

I want both of these to return true.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`is_numeric()`](http://php.net/is_numeric) if you want it to accept floating point values, and [`ctype_digit()`](http://php.net/ctype_digit) for integers only.

Comment: Should use `is_int` for testing for integers, `ctype_digit` checks whether the string contains only numerical digits or not.

Answer (score 2):

You're looking for is_numeric().

http://php.net/is_numeric

Comment: is_numeric and is_int are two different things, however. onc accepts only whole numbers, the other allows decimals, scientific notations, etc.

Answer (score 1):

You can not enclose a variable with quote (single or double quote),
anything enclosed by quote will be treated as string

see :- http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php

Everything return by database (assume is mysql) is always STRING,
for your case, it will be a NUMERIC STRING
function is_numeric (like the rest has mentioned) is the right way to go

> is_numeric — Finds whether a variable is a number or a numeric string

Answer (score 1):

I little hack-ish, but may be a more forceful way to check if the value "matches an integer's pattern". By that I mean it may /may not be cast explicitly to an integer, but it has all the makings of one.

```
function isInt($i){
  return (is_numeric($i)  // number, but not necessarily an integer
       && (int)$i == $i); // when cast it's still the same "number"
}
```

[Example](http://www.ideone.com/5D0N7) (Try your own inputs and see how it stands up)

Answer (score 1):

Cast your variable to the type you want.

The casts allowed are:

- (int), (integer) - cast to integer
- (bool), (boolean) - cast to boolean
- (float), (double), (real) - cast to float
- (string) - cast to string
- (array) - cast to array
- (object) - cast to object
- (unset) - cast to NULL (PHP 5)

**Code:**

```
<?

header( 'content-type: text/plain' );
$var = '10.1';

var_dump( (int)$var );
var_dump( (bool)$var );
var_dump( (float)$var );
var_dump( (string)$var );
var_dump( (array)$var );
var_dump( (object)$var );
var_dump( (unset)$var );
```

**Output:**

```
int(10)
bool(true)
float(10.1)
string(4) "10.1"
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  string(4) "10.1"
}
object(stdClass)#1 (1) {
  ["scalar"]=>
  string(4) "10.1"
}
NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function is_number($s){
    return in_array(str_replace(str_split('0123456789'), '', $s), array(',','.',''));
}
```