# Checking if php variable is a number or not

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What's the correct way to test if a variable is a number in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8409913/whats-the-correct-way-to-test-if-a-variable-is-a-number-in-php)

I have two variables coming in from a form:

```
$minNo = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET["minNo"]);
$maxNo = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET["maxNo"]);
```

How can I check whether they are numerical values or not?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Try [is_numeric](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-numeric.php).

> Finds whether the given variable is numeric. Numeric strings consist
>   of optional sign, any number of digits, optional decimal part and
>   optional exponential part. Thus +0123.45e6 is a valid numeric value.
>   Hexadecimal notation (0xFF) is allowed too but only without sign,
>   decimal and exponential part.

Answer (score 14):

Use [`is_numeric`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-numeric.php) function, it returns bool value:

```
is_numeric($element)
```

Answer (score 6):

You can use [`is_numeric()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-numeric.php) to check if the number is numeric.

To validate as an integer, use...

```
$validInt = filter_var($minNo, FILTER_VALIDATE_INT);
```

Comment: In my case I wanted to check that $_GET['id'] was an integer, otherwise exit. This seems to be the best method. Of course using prepared statement following this.

Answer (score 3):

using is_numeric() function...