# PHPUnit Testing version of assertIsA

Tags: phpunit

Does PHPUnit have an assertion that checks the type of a value

Function:

```
public function getTaxRate()
{
    return 21;  
}
```

I want to test that the value returned is a number.

Sorry but i am new to PHPUnit testing.

I found that SimpleTest has assertIsA(); is there something similar for PHPUnit.

Regards

Comment: The correct equivalent for simple-test `assertIsA();` actually is Phpunit `assertInstanceOf();`. Please double-check you mean the right assertion from simpletest and perhaps provide reference. I refer to: http://simpletest.org/api/SimpleTest/UnitTester/UnitTestCase.html#assertIsA

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The notion that something "is a number" is a little fuzzy in weakly typed languages like php. In php, `1 + "1"` is 2. Is the string `"1"` a number?

The [Phpunit assertion `assertInternalType()`](http://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/writing-tests-for-phpunit.html#writing-tests-for-phpunit.assertions.assertInternalType) might help you:

```
$actual = $subject->getTaxRate();
$this->assertIternalType('int', $actual);
```

But you can't combine assertions with logical operators. So you can't easily express the idea "assert that 42.0 is either an integer or a float". Such more intensive assertions can be grouped into a private helper assertion method:

```
private function assertNumber($actual, $message = "Is a number")  {
    $isScalar = is_scalar($actual);
    $isNumber = $isScalar && (is_int($actual) || is_float($actual));
    $this->assertTrue($isNumber, $message);
}
```

And then you just use it in your tests within the same testcase class:

```
$actual = $subject->getTaxRate();
$this->assertNumber($actual);
```

You can write your own custom assertion as well. This is probably your best bet if you need to run a number-pseudo-type assertion often, unless I've missed something. See [Extending PHPUnit](http://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/extending-phpunit.html) which shows how that is done.

Related:

- [What's the correct way to test if a variable is a number in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8409913/367456)
- http://php.net/is_numeric

Comment: `is_int` won't return true if a numeric string is passed. Use `is_numeric` instead. Thnaks

Comment: It's not at all clear that the OP *wants* to return true when a numeric string is passed.